# iOS: Best practice to know when two view controllers are loaded after navigation push

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, delegates

I have an iOS app that displays multiple screens and has different root controller for both iPhone and iPad.  Here is a simplified example code to show what is going on.

```
if (iPad) {
    self.sideMenuController = [LGSideMenuController sideMenuControllerWithRootViewController:viewControllerA
                                                        leftViewController:viewControllerB
                                                        rightViewController:nil];   
} else {
    self.sideMenuController = [LGSideMenuController sideMenuControllerWithRootViewController:viewControllerB
                                                        leftViewController:viewControllerA
                                                        rightViewController:nil];   
  }

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.sideMenuController animated:NO];
```

I need to be able to tell when both controllers (ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB) is loaded.

I've implemented the following delegate

```
   - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
        if (self.viewControllerA.viewIfLoaded.window != nil && self.viewControllerB.viewIfLoaded.window != nil) {
           // do stuff after both controllers have been loaded and it is current view.
        }
    }
```

The delegate solution works, but not sure if it is best practice. I check if `viewControllerA` and `viewControllerB` is not nil and current view controllers because I push other controllers in the navigation controller and don't want to do anything if that happens.

Comment: I'm just curious: `navigationController.viewControllers.contains(viewControllerA) && navigationController.viewControllers.contains(viewControllerB)` wouldn't work here?

Comment: Also what if we push yet another view controller? You'll get the same call and the condition will pass, but it was neither of those that just got pushed. Is that acceptable. This seems fragile somehow.

Comment: That's a good point. If a new controller did get passed (my app doesn't do that now, but could in future) the condition would pass. I wonder if there is a way around this.

Comment: Also, `navigationController.viewControllers.contains(viewControllerA)` wouldn't work. The navigation controller does know it contains `self.sideMenuController` however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the root view controller always loads first, you could perform work in the `viewDidLoad` method of the non-root view controller, which you could determine by referencing the device type.

Comment: This is what I ended going up with.

Answer (score 1):

It seems fragile. You're making a lot of assumptions and not (as far as I can tell) asking the navigation controller the question you really want to know the answer to. That question would be (as far as I can tell):

- Is the view controller that just got pushed one of VCA and VCB?
- Is the *other* of that pair *already* the navigation controller's child?

Comment: Yes, those are the questions I am asking. Not sure if it is possible through this delegate, however. The delegate is after pushing view controllers. I only want to do certain things once after navigation controller is done pushing.

Comment: Well, once again it's an x-y question. You _still_ are not asking how to do the thing you want to do. Once again, you've just picked a "solution" (the navigation delegate method and some particular code) and asked "how's this?"

Comment: I just need to know when both view controllers are loaded after pushing with my navigation controller. Then, need to call some methods (only once). I tried the delegate solution, but you pointed out flaws I didn't think about (specifically what if I push more controllers). I originally thought the delegate solution would've worked, but seems it has flaws that could cause methods to be called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can have some BaseClass that both viewControllers inherit from (ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB) and in that BaseClass, you can use `viewDidLoad:` method to run whatever code you want.